# React Form validation library

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, jsx

write now we are validating Form using basic validation not using any library.

on submit:

```
  for (let key in requestModel) {
            if (!requestModel[key] && errorObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                errorObject[key] = "This field is required";
                setErrorObject({ ...errorObject });
                document.getElementById(key).scrollIntoView();
                return;
            }
        }

created const requestModel and const errorObject
Added className={errorObject.field && "has-error"}
has-error is the css class.
```

looking for React validation library where I can just define fields and it will be validated and autofocus. like jquery validation. looking lib which is free and simple to use. I tried few but complicated with the current logic.
Please provide an example for simple form.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Formik. Its available on npm public repo to download and use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enfometa/em-forms
npm install @enfometa/em-forms
Documentation:
[www.enfometa.com/documentation](http://www.enfometa.com/documentation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).